# Multidimensional Array Information Grabbing

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks as such:

```
{
"stocks": {
    "0": {
        "name": "Stock Exchange",
        "current_price": 12843.973,
        "available_shares": 0,
    },
    "1": {
        "acronym": "TSBC",
        "current_price": 503.106,
        "available_shares": 171252632,
        "benefit": {
            "requirement": 4000000,
            "description": "Entitled to receive occasional dividends"
        }
    },
```

and from number 1, I need to grab current_price. I have a foreach that grabs it from both, but I'm not sure how to only grab the info from number 1, being the second block of information - TSBC. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no number two, do you mean the second, number 1?

Comment: Yes, OP edited. The second block, TSBC

Answer (score 1):

As you added the `json` tag to your question, I must note that you have presented an invalid json content. There is unexpected comma right after the number `0` within the first "stocks" object `"available_shares": 0,`. 
So let's remove that comma and if we talk about "multidimensional array" let's decode our json string into associative array with `json_decode` function in such way:

```
// $str - is some part of your json string
$str = '{
"stocks": {
    "0": {
        "name": "Stock Exchange",
        "current_price": 12843.973,
        "available_shares": 0
    },
    "1": {
        "acronym": "TSBC",
        "current_price": 503.106,
        "available_shares": 171252632,
        "benefit": {
            "requirement": 4000000,
            "description": "Entitled to receive occasional dividends"
        }
    }}}';

$arr = json_decode($str, true);
// now we are able to get 'current_price' from the second element of array
var_dump($arr['stocks'][1]['current_price']);

// the output:
float 503.106
```